# Multiple app components in angular

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular. I am currently using Meteor+Angular.

I have an `app.component.html` that looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <nav-user></nav-user>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div>
```

I want to support views for both `user` and `admin` in the same application (e.g., under `/admin` and `/user`). This requires a separate navigation component `<nav-admin></nav-admin>` when under `/admin` links.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: btw, I got the routing working with multiple components and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think all you need is *ngIf :

```
<nav-user *ngIf='user.type=="user"'></nav-user>
<nav-admin *ngIf='user.type=="admin"'></nav-admin>
```

Comment: In general, how efficient is this check? does it happen before or after rendering?

Comment: it will be checked on each change , if made on the user model.

Comment: @MFARID , May I expect the upvote and accept answer :) ?

Comment: SO is blocking me from accepting it before a few mins :D

Comment: @MFARID , Thanks :D . Happy coding btw.